# CSS3 animating Keyframes

Tags: css, keyframe

I was wondering if it's possible to rewind my animations, the case is as follows:

I'm animating my nav with css3 keyframes:

```
        @-webkit-keyframes nav /* Safari and Chrome */
        {
            0% {width: 0%; opacity:0.0;}
        100% {width: 22%; opacity:0.5;}
        }

        nav:hover
        {
            animation: nav 3s;
            -moz-animation: nav 3s; /* Firefox */
            -webkit-animation: nav 3s; /* Safari and Chrome */
            -o-animation: nav 3s; /* Opera */
        }
```

Now he expands with a animation when i hover it, no i'm wondering how to rewind the animation even as smooth when i release the hover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use CSS transition to do this.

**Example CSS**

```
nav
{
    width: 0%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition:all 3s ease-in-out;    
}

nav:hover
{
    width: 22%; 
    opacity:0.5;     
}
```

Comment: Makes it alot easier, nice solution !Thanks!